# jQuery Isotope layout initializing with inconsistent spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for a layout. As you can see below, the grid initializes with inconsistent spacing. If I immediately called the `isotope` function again with filtering, the issue persists. But if I wrap it in a `setTimeout`, the issue is fixed.

[image]

Here is the JavaScript that creates the layout with inconsistent spacing:

```
var $container = $('#isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.tag-box',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    sortBy: 'name',
    getSortData: {
        name: '.tag-name'
    }
});

// This will fix the issue:
// setTimeout(function() {
//     $container.isotope({filter: '*'});
// }, 0);

$('#filters').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({filter: filterValue});
});
```

The `setTimeout` is fine for now, but is there a way to initialize the layout with even spacing?

Comment: Seems like an issue with processing delay on filtering. You may try solving with callback function on filter. Disable the filter option on UI after click event and enable it on callback of filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Without a jsfiddle or link it is difficult to see but why use setTimeout when you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

var $container = $('#isotope').isotope({
itemSelector: '.tag-box',
layoutMode: 'fitRows',
filter: '*',
sortBy: 'name',
getSortData: {
    name: '.tag-name'
}
});

});
```